# inludegraphics macro does not ask for width etc. but only for llx, lly

Tags: auctex, debugging

Using GNU Emacs 26.3, I have a tex file with `\usepackage{graphicx}` and AUCTeX enabled. However, inserting a `includegraphics` macro does not prompt for the optional arguments defined in `graphicx.el` `LaTeX-graphicx-key-val-options` but only for `llx, lly` and `urx, ury`.

Any ideas on how to debug the wrong behavior?

Comment: Updating auctex solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`graphicx.el` has this entry for `includegraphics`:

```el
'("includegraphics" (TeX-arg-conditional (member "graphics" (TeX-style-list))
                                         (["llx,lly"] ["urx,ury"])
                                         ([ LaTeX-arg-graphicx-includegraphics-key-val ]))
```

I suspect you're also loading the `graphics` package besides `graphicx` in your .tex file.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I tested with a minimal .tex which exclusively uses `graphicx` and `emacs -q`.